# Diagonal basis for bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}[x]_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

For $f,g \in V =\mathbb{R}[x]_2$, we have the bilinear form 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi : &V \times V &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
       &(f,g)      &\mapsto \int_{-1}^1 xf(x)g(x)dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
I showed that it is degenerate by observing that ker$(\phi_L) = \left\{a_0\left(1 - \frac{5}{3}x^2\right) \in V \mid a_0 \in \mathbb{R}\right\} \neq \{0\}$. (Maybe this is already where it goes wrong.)
I am now to give a basis of $V$ for which the matrix associated to $\phi$ is diagonal. Now while I do have a theorem that guarantees the *existence* of such a basis, a method to *construct* such a basis eludes me. 
$$
H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 &  0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: well, if you can type in the matrix $H$ using the basis $(1,x,x^2),$ so 3 by 3, I can show you quickly how to change; that is, given symmetric $H$ with rational entries, I can show you how to solve $P^T HP = D$ and $Q^T D Q = H$ with $Q = P^{-1},$ entries of $P$ rational, and $\det P = \pm 1$

Comment: I typed in a matrix $H$ with all entries $0,$ all you need to do is correct the entries to the actual inner products, a symmetric matrix. Since you are beginning with the inner product (rather than a polynomial quadratic form), this construction is called the Gram matrix.

Comment: well, if you do edit in the corrections, leave a comment to me here beginning with an "at" sign and and least the first three letters of Will. The next time I look at my main page, there will be a little red flag showing that I have a comment reply and giving a link back here to your comment.

Comment: Good, Please find $(1,1)$ and $(1,x) = (x,1)$ and $(1,x^2)= (x^2,1)$ and $(x,x)$ and $(x,x^2)= (x^2,x)$ and $(x^2,x^2)$ and edit those numbers into the matrix in the correct places

Comment: Thank you very much @WillJagy! I only now see that I can write the matrix associtated to $\phi$ (in some basis $B = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$) as $[\phi(v_j,v_i)]_{i,j}$. (I figure you guessed I knew that already...) For the basis $B = (1,x,x^2)$ I get $H = $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2/3 & 0 
 \\ 2/3 & 0 & 2/5 \\ 0 & 2/5 & 0\end{bmatrix}. To change the basis, I have found a theorem that seems to suggest something along the lines of what you said, so I think I'll get there now myself. Many thanks!

Comment: matrix looks good to me.

Comment: The theorem doesn't seem that do that after all... Can you still show me what you meant by $P^THP= D$?

Comment: posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the columns of $P$ by $( 1,-2, -5)$ suggests the basis
$$ \{ \; 1+x, \; \; 1-x, \; \; 3 - 5 x^2 \; \} $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
\frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 & \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } \\ 
0 & \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
\frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
\frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 & \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } \\ 
0 & \frac{ 2 }{ 5 } & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

ORIGINAL: I multiply your matrix by $15/2$ to get integers. To apply to your specific matrix, multiply both $H$ and $D$ by $2/15.$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$

$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 5 & 3 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
3 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 10 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
10 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 10 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$